# Pass Mysql result into JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Could someone help me out with a small problem and an explantaion on what would be wrong?  What i would like to do is return a result from a MySQL query, and pass it through JSON and display the value. What i have got so far is as follows:

```
$qry = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user_profile";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['first_name'];     
}
```

I am currently getting the error.

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
<div id="profile">
    <div id="photo-frame">
        <img class="circle" src="images/photo.jpg">
    </div>
        <h3 id="name"></h3>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var text =  <?php echo json_encode($name)?>;            
    var obj = JSON.parse(text);
    $('#name').text(obj.name);          

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user_profile" without any WHERE clause may return one or two dimensional array. 
When you use the json_encode to encode your result, the JSON string format will be different for one and two dimensional array. 
*It will cause headache in the Javascript Part*.

**So if this is for a Single Profile- Dont use JSON**

PHP

```
$qry = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user_profile WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if (mysql_num_rows($results) == 1) { 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $name = $row['first_name'];  
   }
}
```

**If this is for Multiple Profile**

PHP

```
$qry = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user_profile";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if (mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
   $jsonData = []; 
   $jsonData['profiles'] =  mysql_fetch_array($result)
   json_encode($jsonData, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

HTML, JAVASCRIPT AND JQUERY

```
<div id="profile"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var data = <?php echo $jsonData;?>; 
    $.each(data.profiles, function() {
      $('#profile').append(
         '<div id="photo-frame">' +
            '<img class="circle" src="images/photo.jpg">' +
         '</div>' +
        '<h3 id="name">' + this.first_name + '&nbsp;' + this.last_name + '</h3>' + 
        '<hr/>'
      );
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.  With my initial thoughts on what I wanted to achieve, I think I was probably getting myself confused.  Which leads me to ask would there actually be a need  for pulling data from a database and passing it to a JSON script, or is there an example of when that process would be used?

Comment: You are welcome .. JSON is a interchangeable data format like XML ... Which means you can pull out the data from the database turn it into JSON and readily use it, not only in PHP / ASP / Javascript (Web Applications), but with others  e.g. JAVA / C# Applications which includes Desktop Programs, Smartphone Apps, RSS Readers etc. Use your imagination after that.

Answer (score 0):

this is not json u have in $name (its plane text) try:

```
var text =  <?php echo $name; ?>;
```

but keep in mind that this is not a good coding style php>js>html

remove the "obj" part. just:

```
$('#name').text(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to use `json` here, you can simply:

```
<?php
$qry = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user_profile";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['first_name'];     
}

?>

<div id="profile">
    <div id="photo-frame">
        <img class="circle" src="images/photo.jpg">
    </div>
        <h3 id="name"></h3>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var text =  '<?=$name;?>';            
    $('#name').text(text);          

</script>
```